# Install MySql in raspberrypi and put a data into a table using python3

Tags: python, mysql

I am woking a problem where i am getting the GPS data in raspberrypi. Because of incompatibility issues, i have to use python3 only. Basically, i have to print a string into a column of a table in the mysql server of raspberrypi. I am sitting on this problem, but i am not able to do it. I know, i am asking a lot, but it is genuine problem.
I tried this link:
https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html

The installations steps i followed were:

sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install python3-mysqldb
sudo apt-get install mysql-server python3-mysqldb
sudo mysql_secure_installation
sudo mysqladmin -u root -p create intruder  // intruder is database name
sudo mysql intruder -u root -p

mysql>  CREATE TABLE gps(GPSData VARCHAR(200)NOT NULL);

I am putting the code below what i tried. 
The Error i am getting is

pymysql.err.InternalError: (1698, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'")
I have tried a lot, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance.Please help.

```
import pymysql.cursors

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='passwd',
                             db='intruder',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

  with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    # Create a new record
    sql = "INSERT INTO `gps` ( `GPSData`) VALUES (%s)"
    cursor.execute(sql, ('HelloWorld'))


connection.commit()
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a non-root user and save this one in case you lose the password:

```
sudo mysql

create user gps@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'securepassword';
GRANT ALL ON intruder.* TO gps@localhost;
```

Then use:

```
 connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                         user='gps',
                         password='securepassword',
                         db='intruder', ...
```

Comment: Thank you sir. But i am stil getting the same error.